# error with using include_once in php

Tags: php

I have a file header where i have created variables for all the paths i need, like this:

```
$GLOBAL_stylePath = "http://localhost/pspace/css/";
```

(if i shouldn't use http  in the above, then how would it be? C://htdocs/xampp/pspace/css/   ???)

```
include_once "/classes/authorizationUtils.php";
$authorizationUtils = new AuthorizationUtils();
```

anyways, the includes are messing up everything and giving me errors such as:

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\pspace\includes\header.php on line 12
```

how can i enable this configuration in my php.in. i have a variable allow_url_include=off, when i "on" it, no changes happen. and also this:

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'http://localhost/pspace/classes/authorizationUtils.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pspace\includes\header.php on line 12
```

Comment: Are you including CSS files? Also, `/classes` refers to the filesystem (disk) root, this is probably wrong.

Comment: no, i m not including the css, just gave that as an example of the variables. classes would be wrong? u mean, any reserved name or what?

Comment: No. You are prepending `classes` with a slash (i.e.: `/classes`), which, like I said, probably refers to the filesystem root.

Comment: ok, any idea on what to do with this:

Comment: Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'authorizationUtils.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pspace\includes\header.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you editing the correct php.ini file. Usually there are two php.ini files associated with your installation. One is used for the command line interface php and the other for the server side php. Make sure that you make the changes to both.
2. Make sure that you restart your webserver after these changes are made.

Comment: what kind of changes? u mean turning allow_url_include to on instead of off in php.in, php.ini-development and php.ini-production? its not working.

Comment: You don't really need to change the one for PHP CLI -- and to be sure you're changing the right one, phpinfo() will show you, among other things, the path of the php.ini file that is being used.

Comment: Can you also check allow_url_fopen in php.ini. Please set that to "1"

Comment: i did, not working. and the values are on and off, not 1 and 0.

Comment: Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: Does this C:\xampp\php\PEAR exist on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

This warning :

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'http://localhost/pspace/classes/authorizationUtils.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pspace\includes\header.php on line 12
```

it means that you try to include file which could not be found in [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path). So, what you need is to define your `include_path`.

If your directory listing is like this :

1. c:\xampp\htdocs\pspace\              `// as your root`
2. c:\xampp\htdocs\pspace\includes\
3. c:\xampp\htdocs\pspace\classes\

Try this :

```
<?php  
    $path1 = '.\includes\';  
    $path2 = '.\classes\';
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path1 . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path2);
?>
```

Your also can change relative path `$path1 = '.\includes\';` to absolute path `$path1 = 'c:\xampp\htdocs\pspace\includes\';`

Read this to understand more about [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) and about [include function](http://id2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) that always include files based on file path given. Hope this can help.