# How to include file if include is disable in php.ini

Tags: php

I have couple php files what i need to include in index.php file, but when i use require_once or include, page cannot be loaded. I know it is because server don't allow that. How can i include or require_once file on different way? Code is this

```
require_once'php/lib/session.php';
sec_session();
```

I got this error in chrome
[image]

Comment: please post your code

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What happens if before the require, you add `var_dump(file_exists('php/lib/session.php')); exit;`? Chances are it will return false as the file isn't where you've told it. If that's the case, then require_once will fatal, killing your page.

Comment: after adding var_dump(file_exists('php/lib/session.php')); exit; i see no difference

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044617/error-with-using-include-once-in-php

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - but that's an *HTTP 500 Internal Server Error* being displayed in Chrome - even a fatal PHP error won't result in that, I suspect there's something else going on here...

Comment: @CD001 For reference, the screenshot was added _after_ I commented on fatal errors :)

Comment: Next step I suppose is to ask for the code in session.php and see if there's a syntax error. OR, check your errors logs!

Comment: code is right and work on my localhost but dont work on server because i use in code require_once

Answer (score 0):

There is an other way. But a dirty one:

```
//read the file
$phpCode = file_get_contents('/path/to/file/to/include.php');
//eval the code 
eval('?>'.$phpCode.'<?php;');
```

But if your host block the basic "include" function, great are the odds that eval is blocked too...